# NodeJS combining object array range properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

the title may be a bit confusing but I'll explain it in detail. I have a table in UI and user can choose date ranges from there like;

monday - {in:"13:00:00",out:"13:59:59"}

tuesday - [{in:"13:00:00",out:"13:59:59"},{in:"14:00:00",out:"14:59:59"}]

user can only choose multiple hour intervals for one day. I already made the grouping the intervals according to their date and combining the intervals like

tuesday- [{in:"13:00:00",out:"14:59:59"},{in:"14:00:00",out:"14:59:59"}]

in the first iteration. But I couldn't figure out how to make it for more than 4 or 5 hour intervals.FYI I'm using lodash for sorting and grouping and moment for converting hours to int.

If user enters 5 intervals for tuesday like [{in:"13:00:00",out:"13:59:59"},{in:"14:00:00",out:"14:59:59"},{in:"15:00:00",out:"15:59:59"},{in:"18:00:00",out:"18:59:59"},{in:"19:00:00",out:"19:59:59"}]

I want ranges to be combined like ;

[{in:"13:00:00",out:"15:59:59"},{in:"18:00:00",out:"19:59:59"}]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What is the minimum unit of time a range can be different from another to get combined? A second? Is a range simply an array of `Date` instances? Or are they strings/numbers/whatever?

Comment: I use moment.valueOf() for converting hours into int miliseconds and make the comparison if ((item[i+1].in-item[i].out)<=1000) then flag=true and I combine the ranges. But I couldn't figure out how to make it for example if there are 4 consecutive hour intervals. I have to make them as one object but couldn't do it.

Comment: You try to generate the union of the time slices however `[{in:"13:00:00",out:"14:59:59"},{in:"15:00:00",out:"15:59:59"}]` has one second separation so they do not intersect. How about that..? Of course it can still be done but i suppose `[{in:"13:00:00",out:"15:00:00"},{in:"15:00:00",out:"16:00:00"}]` could have been more meaningful both for the coder and the user.

Comment: I'm working with 24-hours clock so the thing you mention throws error in my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input data is chronological then one way of implementing your reduced time table is this;

```js
var timeSlices = [{in:"13:00:00",out:"13:59:59"},{in:"14:00:00",out:"14:59:59"},{in:"15:00:00",out:"15:59:59"},{in:"18:00:00",out:"18:59:59"},{in:"19:00:00",out:"19:59:59"}],
            ts = new Date(),
            te = new Date(),
       reduced = timeSlices.reduce((p,c) => {p.length ? (ts.setHours(...p[p.length-1].out.split(":")),
                                                         te.setHours(...c.in.split(":")),
                                                         te-ts <= 1000 ? p[p.length-1].out = c.out
                                                                       : p.push(c))
                                                      : p.push(c);
                                             return p;},[]);
console.log(reduced);
```

However if the objects with in and out times are located arbitrary in the array then a more conceptual approach like first sorting them according to their in times would be essential. That wouldn't be a big deal though.

Comment: I made the sorting and grouping according to day. Let me try your answer.

Comment: @Fatih Aktepe: Then i suppose it can not deal with the arrow functions thus ES6 code. Then it presumably will also complain about the spread operator as well. Have you got the logic behind the code? Then you can replicate it in ES5? Or as another idea you can also copy paste the code at https://babeljs.io/repl/ on the left pane and on the right you will get the ES5 version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ranges are composed of [Moment](//momentjs.com) instances and you wanted to combine any two ranges where the end of one range either overlapped another range or was less than or equal to one second behind the start of another range, this function should be able to combine the ranges

```
function combineRanges (ranges) {
  if (ranges.length <= 1) {
    return ranges
  }
  ranges = ranges.sort(byStart)
  var current = ranges[0]
  var combined = [current]
  for (var i = 1; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var next = ranges[i]
    if (current.out.diff(next.in, 'seconds') > 1) {
      combined.push(next)
      current = next
    } else if (current.out.isBefore(next.out)) {
      current.out = next.out
    }
  }
  return combined
}

function byStart (a, b) {
  return a.in - b.in
}
```

Comment: this will combine 4 consecutive ranges into one range?

Comment: @FatihAktepe it should, assuming a range look kinda like: `{ in: moment(), out: moment() }`

Comment: I'll implement your solution and update the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution does not apply on distent hour intervals.